# Error uploading excel file to CKAN datastore

Tags: datastore, ckan

I have a CKAN 2.8 installed on an Ubuntu 16.04 server and I have successfully  configured filestore, datastore and datapusher. Whenever I try to upload a to datastore, I get the message "Error: Process completed but unable to post to result_url" and the status says pending. I have set SSL_VERIFY to FALSE in datapusher_settings.py but the error kept coming. Anyone who can help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the DataPusher and uploading a file manually to the DataStore? You can do that after creating the resource by editing the resource and choosing "Upload to the DataStore" from the "DataStore" tab. This will tell you whether the problem is with the DataStore (if manual upload doesn't work either) or with the DataPusher (if manual upload works, but automatic upload doesn't).

Comment: Thanks for your response Florian. But if I disable DataPusher by removing it from list of plugins in production.ini, the DataStore tab will not be displayed. When DataPusher is active and I clicked "Upload to DataStore" button, it brings same error "Error: Process completed but unable to post to result_url".

Comment: OK. Is your `site_url` setting in your CKAN INI file correct? Is there anything in the DataPusher or CKAN logs?

Comment: Thanks @FlorianBrucker. This is what I found in the logs. <br> [wsgi:error] [pid 26074:tid 139681541789440] HTTPError: Access denied: <function datastore_create at 0x7f0a1b6f4e60> requires an authenticated user status=403 url=my_host/api/3/action/datastore_create response={"help": "my_host/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create", "success": false, "error": {"message": "Access denied: <function datastore_create at 0x7f0a1b6f4e60> requires an authenticated user", "__type": "Authorization Error"}}

Comment: OK. Are you running the DataPusher on the same host as CKAN?

Comment: Yes. I am running datapusher on the same host as CKAN.

Comment: Can you try to manually call `datastore_create`, for example via `curl`? See [the DataStore documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/datastore.html#the-datastore-api) for details. Make sure to include an `Authorization` header with your API key, see [this part of the CKAN docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/index.html#authentication-and-api-keys).